# How do I compute derivative using Numpy?

Tags: python, math, numpy

How do I calculate the derivative of a function, for example

> y = x<sup>2</sup>+1

using `numpy`?

Let's say, I want the value of derivative at x = 5...

Comment: You need to use Sympy: http://sympy.org/en/index.html
Numpy is a numeric computation library for Python

Comment: Alternatively, do you want a method for estimating the numerical value of the derivative? For this you can use a finite difference method, but bear in mind they tend to be horribly noisy.

Comment: [Finite-difference approximation of the gradient of a scalar function](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Scipy/generated/scipy.optimize.approx_fprime.html)

Answer (score 205, accepted):

You have four options

1. [Finite Differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_differences)
2. [Automatic Derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation)
3. [Symbolic Differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_differentiation)
4. Compute derivatives by hand.

Finite differences require no external tools but are prone to numerical error and, if you're in a multivariate situation, can take a while.

Symbolic differentiation is ideal if your problem is simple enough. Symbolic methods are getting quite robust these days. [SymPy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html) is an excellent project for this that integrates well with NumPy. Look at the autowrap or lambdify functions or check out [Jensen's blogpost about a similar question](http://ojensen.wordpress.com/).

Automatic derivatives are very cool, aren't prone to numeric errors, but do require some additional libraries (google for this, there are a few good options). This is the most robust but also the most sophisticated/difficult to set up choice.  If you're fine restricting yourself to `numpy` syntax then [Theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/) might be a good choice.

Here is an example using SymPy

```
In [1]: from sympy import *
In [2]: import numpy as np
In [3]: x = Symbol('x')
In [4]: y = x**2 + 1
In [5]: yprime = y.diff(x)
In [6]: yprime
Out[6]: 2⋅x

In [7]: f = lambdify(x, yprime, 'numpy')
In [8]: f(np.ones(5))
Out[8]: [ 2.  2.  2.  2.  2.]
```

Comment: Sorry, if this seems stupid, What is the differences between 3.Symbolic Differentiation and 4.by hand differentiation??

Comment: When I said "symbolic differentiation" I intended to imply that the process was handled by a computer. In principle 3 and 4 differ only by who does the work, the computer or the programmer. 3 is preferred over 4 due to consistency, scalability, and laziness. 4 is necessary if 3 fails to find a solution.

Comment: In line 7 we made f, a function that computes the derivative of y wrt x. In 8 we apply this derivative function to a vector of all ones and get the vector of all twos. This is because, as stated in line 6, yprime = 2*x.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, you can also do differentiation by integration (see Cauchy's integral formula), it is implemented e.g. in `mpmath` (not sure however what they exactly do).

Comment: Is there an easy way to do finite differences in numpy without implementing it yourself? e.g. I want to find the gradient of a function at predefined points.

Comment: Theano is kindof dead. Look at pytorch or JAX or basically any "deep learning" toolbox. Autodiff is one of its pillars.

Answer (score 79):

The most straight-forward way I can think of is using [numpy's gradient function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html):

```
x = numpy.linspace(0,10,1000)
dx = x[1]-x[0]
y = x**2 + 1
dydx = numpy.gradient(y, dx)
```

This way, dydx will be computed using central differences and will have the same length as y, unlike numpy.diff, which uses forward differences and will return (n-1) size vector.

Comment: What if dx isn't constant?

Comment: @weberc2, in that case you should divide one vector by another, but treat the edges separately with forward and backward derivatives manually.

Comment: Or you could interpolate y with a constant dx, then calculate the gradient.

Comment: @Sparkler Thanks for your suggestion. If I may ask 2 small questions, (i) why do we pass `dx` to `numpy.gradient` instead of `x`? (ii) Can we also do the last line of yours as follows: `dydx = numpy.gradient(y, numpy.gradient(x))`?

Comment: As of v1.13, non uniform spacing can be specified using an array as the second argument. See the Examples section of [this page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html#numpy.gradient).

Comment: `edge_order=2` is more accurate than the default `edge_order=1`, and hardly slower; try `x = np.linspace( 0, 2, 21 );  y = x**3;  g = np.gradient( y, x, edge_order=1 );  print(   "np.gradient( x^3 ) - 3x^2: \n", g - 3 * x**2 )`

Answer (score 36):

NumPy does not provide general functionality to compute derivatives.  It can handles the simple special case of polynomials however:

```
>>> p = numpy.poly1d([1, 0, 1])
>>> print p
   2
1 x + 1
>>> q = p.deriv()
>>> print q
2 x
>>> q(5)
10
```

If you want to compute the derivative numerically, you can get away with using central difference quotients for the vast majority of applications.  For the derivative in a single point, the formula would be something like

```
x = 5.0
eps = numpy.sqrt(numpy.finfo(float).eps) * (1.0 + x)
print (p(x + eps) - p(x - eps)) / (2.0 * eps * x)
```

if you have an array `x` of abscissae with a corresponding array `y` of function values, you can comput approximations of derivatives with

```
numpy.diff(y) / numpy.diff(x)
```

Comment: 'Computing numerical derivatives for more general case is easy' -- I beg to differ, computing numerical derivatives for general cases is quite difficult.  You just chose nicely behaved functions.

Comment: what does 2 mean after >>>print p ?? (on 2nd line)

Comment: @DrStrangeLove: That's the exponent.  It's meant to simulate mathematical notation.

Comment: @SvenMarnach is it maximum exponent?? or what?? Why does it think exponent is 2?? We inputted only coefficients...

Comment: @DrStrangeLove: The output is supposed to be read as `1 * x**2 + 1`.  They put the `2` in the line above because it's an exponent.  Look at it from a distance.

Comment: @SvenMarnach now, i see..) But what if i had x^3+1 and the same coefficients numpy.poly1d([1, 0, 1]) will it give me 1x+x^3+1?? How does it know the right exponent??

Comment: @DrStrangeLove: To get that, you'd need to use `numpy.poly1d([1, 0, 0, 1])`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thanks!! Earlier, you said that if i want to get 2*x result - "i can't" get it. but in your example 2*x is there! How come??

Comment: @DrStrangeLove: You asked for derivatives in general, and you can't do symbolic derivatives with NumPy in general.  You can merely do it for the trivial case of polynomials.

Answer (score 22):

Assuming you want to use `numpy`, you can numerically compute the derivative of a function at any point using the  [Rigorous definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation):

```
def d_fun(x):
    h = 1e-5 #in theory h is an infinitesimal
    return (fun(x+h)-fun(x))/h
```

You can also use the [Symmetric derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative) for better results:

```
def d_fun(x):
    h = 1e-5
    return (fun(x+h)-fun(x-h))/(2*h)
```

Using your example, the full code should look something like:

```
def fun(x):
    return x**2 + 1

def d_fun(x):
    h = 1e-5
    return (fun(x+h)-fun(x-h))/(2*h)
```

Now, you can **numerically** find the derivative at `x=5`:

```
In [1]: d_fun(5)
Out[1]: 9.999999999621423
```

Comment: This is a beautiful application of the fundamental definition of the derivative. I've always wondered why I needed to learn that (other than to understand the idea of secant approaching tangent). Well, now I know.

Comment: I would add the function as a parameter: `def d_func(func, x):`

Comment: @rb3652 First in foremost it is used to derive all the rules of derivatives. Secondly, it is also often used in mathematical proofs. Just to name a few applications.

Answer (score 12):

I'll throw another method on the pile...

`scipy.interpolate`'s many interpolating splines are capable of providing derivatives.  So, using a linear spline (`k=1`), the derivative of the spline (using the `derivative()` method) should be equivalent to a forward difference.  I'm not entirely sure, but I believe using a cubic spline derivative would be similar to a centered difference derivative since it uses values from before and after to construct the cubic spline.

```
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline

# Get a function that evaluates the linear spline at any x
f = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, y, k=1)

# Get a function that evaluates the derivative of the linear spline at any x
dfdx = f.derivative()

# Evaluate the derivative dydx at each x location...
dydx = dfdx(x)
```

Comment: just tried this, i keep getting errors from this function 
AxisError: axis -1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0
and I dont see any answers to this on the community either , any help ?

Comment: Post your problem as a new question and link to it here. Providing an example that causes your error to occur will probably be needed. Errors I have with interp functions are usually because the data isn't well formed going in - like repeated values, wrong number of dimensions, one of the arrays is accidentally empty, data isn't sorted against x or when sorted isn't a valid function, etc. It's possible scipy is calling numpy incorrectly, but very unlikely. Check x.shape and y.shape. See if np.interp() works - it may provide a more helpful error if not.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `scipy`, which is pretty straight forward:

[`scipy.misc.derivative(func, x0, dx=1.0, n=1, args=(), order=3)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.derivative.html)

> Find the nth derivative of a function at a point.

In your case:

```
from scipy.misc import derivative

def f(x):
    return x**2 + 1

derivative(f, 5, dx=1e-6)
# 10.00000000139778
```

Comment: `scipy.misc.derivative` is deprecated from SciPy 1.10 https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.derivative.html

Answer (score 7):

To calculate gradients, the machine learning community uses Autograd:

> "[Efficiently computes derivatives of numpy code.](https://pypi.org/project/autograd/)"

To install:

```
pip install autograd
```

Here is an example:

```
import autograd.numpy as np
from autograd import grad

def fct(x):
    y = x**2+1
    return y

grad_fct = grad(fct)
print(grad_fct(1.0))
```

It can also compute gradients of complex functions, e.g. multivariate functions.

Comment: Hi can this function be used to differentiate between two columns of data numerically by providing the step length ? thanks

Comment: This was answered more than 3 years ago, but autograd is not being developed anymore (just maintained).  autograd's Main developers now point you to https://github.com/google/jax

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the level of precision you require you can work it out yourself, using the simple proof of differentiation:

```
>>> (((5 + 0.1) ** 2 + 1) - ((5) ** 2 + 1)) / 0.1
10.09999999999998
>>> (((5 + 0.01) ** 2 + 1) - ((5) ** 2 + 1)) / 0.01
10.009999999999764
>>> (((5 + 0.0000000001) ** 2 + 1) - ((5) ** 2 + 1)) / 0.0000000001
10.00000082740371
```

we can't actually take the limit of the gradient, but its kinda fun.
You gotta watch out though because

```
>>> (((5+0.0000000000000001)**2+1)-((5)**2+1))/0.0000000000000001
0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

To compute the derivative of a numerical function, use this second order finite differences scheme as seen in:
https://youtu.be/5QnToSn_oxk?t=1804

```
dx = 0.01
x = np.arange(-4, 4+dx, dx)
y = np.sin(x)
n = np.size(x)

yp = np.zeros(n)
yp[0] = (-3*y[0] + 4*y[1] - y[2]) / (2*dx)
yp[n-1] = (3 * y[n-1] - 4*y[n-2] + y[n-3]) / (2*dx)
for j in range(1,n-1):
    yp[j] = (y[j+1] - y[j-1]) / (2*dx)
```

Or if you want to use a higher order, use:
https://youtu.be/5QnToSn_oxk?t=1374

All that comes from the Nathan Kutz' lectures of the course "Beginning Scientific Computing".