# What is the equivalent of Matlabs differentiate function in numpy?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I have a function and I use polynomial approximation of the function in Matlab, then I calculate the differentiate of the function

```
ppp = fit(x,y, 'poly9')
polydiff = differentiate(ppp, x)
```

I would like to do the same in numpy

```
fx = np.polyfit( x.T, y.T, 9 )
```

What is the equivalent function of the differentiate?

Comment: Did you see this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876290/how-do-i-compute-derivative-using-numpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean `polyder()`? The equivalent is `np.polyder()`

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyder.html

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyder.html

edit: Just realized you're talking about the symbolic math toolbox, which I'm not too familiar with. See Danny M's comment for the symbolic equivalent.