# Implementation of the first derivative of a normal probability distribution function in python

Tags: python, scipy, normal-distribution, derivative

I'm searching for the formula of the first derivative of a normal pdf. Is there a function in numpy or scipy to obtain it directly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compute derivative using Numpy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876290/how-do-i-compute-derivative-using-numpy)

Comment: Not duplicate. This is a specific application of calculus with a precise answer, whereas the linked answer discusses general methodologies.

Answer (score 3):

The PDF of the normal distribution is:

```
scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma)
```

Its derivative with respect to x is:

```
scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma)*(mu - x)/sigma**2
```