# python-graph derivative of a graph/data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have data and i can graph it using matplotlib. Now, is there a way to graph the derivative of that graph/data in python without importing any other modules? (I already have numpy and matplotlib)

I do not have an equation for my data. The data is simply the times that a sensor was touched. I want to draw a graph that shows the rate at which the sensor was touched as time passes on (the derivative of the first graph).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compute derivative using Numpy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876290/how-do-i-compute-derivative-using-numpy)

Comment: @Sait that is taking derivative of an equation. I don't have an equation; I just want to graph the derivative of my current graph

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26042315/547820) or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19787144/547820) on the same page.