# How to calculate derivatives at the boundary in SciPy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, derivative

I have a script drawing a set of `(x,y)` curves at various `z`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
z = np.linspace(0,30,30)

def y(z, x):
    return z**(1-x)

for i in z:
    plt.plot(x, y(i,x))
```

How can I draw `dy/dx` at `x=0` versus `z`?

```
plt.plot(z, dy/dx at x=0)
```

In fact, I need to calculate the slope at the `x=0` boundary for each `(x,y)` curve (shown below), then plot the slopes against `z`.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the [`derivative`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.derivative.html) function:

> **scipy.misc.derivative(func, x0, dx=1.0, n=1, args=(), order=3)**
>
> Find the n-th derivative of a function at a point.
>
> Given a function, use a central difference formula with spacing dx to
>   compute the n-th derivative at x0.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> **func :** function Input function.
>
> **x0 :** float The point at which n-th derivative is found.
>
> **dx :** float, optional Spacing.
>
> **n :** int,optional Order of the derivative. Default is 1.
>
> **args :** tuple, optional
>   Arguments order : int, optional Number of points to use, must be odd.

In your case:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.misc import derivative

x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
z = np.linspace(0,30,30)

x0 = 0

def y(z, x):
    return z**(1-x)

dydx = [derivative(lambda x : y(zi, x) , x0) for zi in z]

plt.plot(z, dydx)

plt.show()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You mixed up the variables in the description. I assume you have a function y in variables (x,z). So you need to calculate dy/dx and dy/dz.

You have a few options to calculate the derivative, including symbolic calcultation (using SymPY) or just straightfoward finite differences calculation (prone to numerical errors) See this: [How do I compute derivative using Numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876290/how-do-i-compute-derivative-using-numpy).

But, you cannot plot this derivative since you are calculating it at a point (x=0,z=0), therefore the result is a float number, and not a function. To make the plot you want you need to calculate the general symbolic derivative (dydx) and make the plot you suggested. To get the result at point (0,0), just dydx(0,0).

Btw, `dydz = (1-x)z**(-x)`  and `dydx = -ln(z)*z**(1-x)`   using [this](https://www.derivative-calculator.net/).

Comment: I do not need `dy/dz`. Each curve shown is `x,y` at a fixed `z`. I need to calculate `dy/dx` for each curve shown at `x=0`. Then plotting the points against corresponding `z` value.