# partial derivative of a custom function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, optimization

I am looking for some pointers and resources on whether the following can be efficiently done in Python.

I have a custom function:

```
def outerfunc(innerfunc(<inputs>), arg1, arg2):
```

computing `outerfunc` returns a numeric value, let's call it *result*

`innerfunc`accepts a few arguments, one of which is a list of numbers, `[x1,x2,x3]`and returns an object which is used to perform the calculation

**objective:**

calculate the sensitivity of *result* to a perturbation (finite amount) of each of `[x1,x2,x3]` so as to obtain a vector of 3 elements - the partial derivatives of *result* w.r.t. x1, x2, and x3

any resources, examples, advice would be appreciated!

edit: i should elaborate that `innerfunc` in this example could come from a third-party source and is not directly built on numpy or edit-able. this is where i am not able to find much references online

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compute derivative using Numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876290/how-do-i-compute-derivative-using-numpy)

Comment: thanks for the link. I am still a little bit unsure how this might work in the case where the innerfunc is not 'simple'/'closed-form. for example, what if internally it were performing some kind of monte-carlo simulation as opposed to a straightforward expression

Comment: @laszlopanaflex. Numeric derivatives aren't all that useful if your function is not continuous.